# SpreadsheetApp getActiveRange().setBorder not contiguous

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an odd occurrence formatting cells in a Google Docs Spreadsheet.

I am incrementing i in a for loop using the following code with:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var curRange = Utilities.formatString("A%d:H%d",i,i);
spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Current").setActiveSelection(curRange);
```

This sets the selection to the row I want, columns A-H.

When I apply formatting to the selection like this:

```
var fontStyle = defaults.getRange("B" + s).getFontStyle();
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setFontStyle(fontStyle);
var fontWeight = defaults.getRange("B" + s).getFontWeight();
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setFontWeight(fontWeight);
var bg = defaults.getRange("B" + s).getBackground();
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setBackground(bg);
```

they are applied to the desired range as expected.

However, when I use the same selection to set a top border line, it appears in cells B-D and G-K (skipping A and E-F). Both affect 8 columns, but the borders are not contiguous.

Here is the code for applying the border:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false);
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

There is an (already) [old issue(23)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=23) concerning `setBorder` that makes it an unreliable method... I've had a few problems in similar use cases.